# Scrapy spider that get two pictures at same page then names them differently

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm new both to Python and Scrapy so I'm not sure I've chosen the best method for doing this; but my aim is to get two (or more) different pictures at a page and naming the pictures differently.

How should I set up the pipeline, should I do a combined pipline or in separated pipelines? Now I've tried separated pipelines but can't make it work. The first picture downloads and renames perfectly, but the second one does not download at all (error message below).

I'm practicing at this page: http://www.allabolag.se/2321000016/STOCKHOLMS_LANS_LANDSTING

allabolagspider.py

```
class allabolagspider(CrawlSpider):
name="allabolagspider"
# allowed_domains = ["byralistan.se"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.allabolag.se/2321000016/STOCKHOLMS_LANS_LANDSTING"
]

pipelines = ['AllabolagPipeline', 'AllabolagPipeline2']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = "http://www.allabolag.se/2321000016/STOCKHOLMS_LANS_LANDSTING"), callback='parse_link'),
)

def parse_link(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@class="reportTable"]'):#//TODO==king it seems that IMDB has changed the html structure for these information
        image = AllabolagItem()
                    tmptitle = response.xpath('''.//tr[2]/td[2]/table//tr[13]/td/span/text()''').extract()
                    tmptitle.insert(0, "logo-")
                    image['title'] = ["".join(tmptitle)]
                    rel = response.xpath('''.//tr[5]/td[2]/div[1]/div/a/img/@src''').extract()
                    image['image_urls'] = [urljoin(response.url, rel[0])]
                    yield image

    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@class="mainWindow"]'):#//TODO==king it seems that IMDB has changed the html structure for these information
        image2 = AllabolagItem()
                    tmptitle2 = response.xpath('''./div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[6]/a/text()''').extract()
                    tmptitle2.insert(0, "hej-")
                    image2['title2'] = ["".join(tmptitle2)]
                    rel2 = response.xpath('''./div[3]/div[1]/a/img/@src''').extract()
                    image2['image_urls2'] = [urljoin(response.url, rel2[0])]
                    yield image2
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'allabolag'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['allabolag.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'allabolag.spiders'

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2.5
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 250

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'allabolag.pipelines.AllabolagPipeline': 1,
'allabolag.pipelines.AllabolagPipeline2': 2,
}

IMAGES_STORE = 'Imagesfolder'
```

pipelines.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
import sqlite3 as lite
from allabolag import settings
from allabolag import items
con = None

class AllabolagPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def set_filename(self, response):
        return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'][0])

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'title': item['title']})

    def get_images(self, response, request, info):
        for key, image, buf in super(AllabolagPipeline, self).get_images(response, request, info):
            key = self.set_filename(response)
        yield key, image, buf

class AllabolagPipeline2(ImagesPipeline):
    def set_filename(self, response):
        return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title2'][0])

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url2 in item['image_urls2']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url2, meta={'title2': item['title2']})

    def get_images(self, response, request, info):
        for key, image, buf in super(AllabolagPipeline2, self).get_images(response, request, info):
            key = self.set_filename2(response)
        yield key, image, buf
```

copy paste from terminal

```
2016-03-08 22:15:58 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'image_urls': [u'http://www.allabolag.se/img/prv/2798135.JPG'],
 'images': [{'checksum': 'a567ec7c2bd99fd7eb20db42229a1bf9',
             'path': 'full/0280bf8228087cd571e86f43859552f9880e558a.jpg',
             'url': 'http://www.allabolag.se/img/prv/2798135.JPG'}],
 'title': [u'logo-UTDELNINGSADRESS']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 45, in process_item
dlist = [self._process_request(r, info) for r in requests]
  File "/Users/VickieB/Documents/Scrapy/Test1/tutorial/tandlakare/allabolag/pipelines.py", line 36, in get_media_requests
for image_url2 in item['image_urls2']:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/item.py", line 56, in __getitem__
return self._values[key]
KeyError: 'image_urls2'
```

Comment: `ImagesPipeline` expects 2 fields, `images` and `image_urls`, so stick to these field names (unless you rewrite an ImagesPipeline to handle "image_urls2"). It seems to me that you're doing the same thing for all the images, using a "title" value from meta, so 1 pipeline is enough for this. Yielding multiple items, from 2 different loops on selectors  (what you're already doing), using "title" field to update `meta` in `get_media_requests()` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I rewrote it with one timeline and made it work.

Answer (score 1):

There might be several bugs I haven't noticed but I *can* explain one of them... 
`KeyError` generally signifies a failed dictionary lookup. In this case it means that, at some point during execution, you're passing an `item` (a dictionary) to `def get_media_requests(self, item, info):` that doesn't have the key  "image_urls2"

Changing `get_media_requests` to this will show you when and should allow the script to keep executing.

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    if "image_urls2" not in item:
        print("ERROR - 'image_urls2' NOT IN ITEM/DICT")
    else:
        for image_url2 in item['image_urls2']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url2, meta={'title2': item['title2']})
```

If you're lazy or don't care about a few missing values, you could enclose the whole thing in `try/except` like so:

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    try:
        for image_url2 in item['image_urls2']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url2, meta={'title2': item['title2']})
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```